# How to edit 'clip' CSS property in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to edit this 'clip' CSS property:

```
#bulb_light {
   position: absolute;
   clip:rect(260px, 160px, 260px, 0px);
}
```

But not normally, rather, thanks to Jquery's help, so I tried this:

//**CSS editing** :

```
$("#bulb_light").css('clip', function () {
        return 'rect(' + newy + 'px, 160px, 260px, 0px);';
    });
```

which is inside a click event:

```
$('#Wsender').click(function () {
**//CSS editing** });
```

**NOTE** that '*newy*' is the variable I created which should take the place of the first parameter of the 'clip' property:

```
rect(newypx, 160px, 260px, 0px);
```

meant to be like that.

The **issue** is that the code is not working when I add this feature with JQuery, but I've found it right in here on StackOverflow. What might be wrong?

[Here is the full source code for reference](http://goo.gl/etRJPt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a minor issue, you can't put a semi-colon at the end of the CSS value for this to work:

```
$("#bulb_light").css('clip', function () {
    return 'rect(' + newy + 'px, 160px, 260px, 0px)' /* <-- Removed semicolon */;
});
```

Additionally, I'm not sure where `newy` is defined, you may not need a function callback for this unless `newy` is to be calculated for each element:

```
$("#bulb_light").css('clip', 'rect(' + newy + 'px, 160px, 260px, 0px)');
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot! Insane but the fact is JSFiddle suggested me to add that semicolon :) Anyway now it's perfectly working, thanks again and have a great day man!